# ASP.NET triggers callback after postback

Tags: asp.net

I have quite complex project and something strange occurs. Page contains AJAX controls, custom controls (which contain also other custom controls) etc.
When page's dropdown control selected item changes, AutoPostBack event fires = This is fine. But, after processing of the postback event, Page_Load event is fired again with IsPostBack = false ... so the page tries to initialize again. I cannot figure out why ... 

Does anybody have some idea (from this brief description), why is this happenning?

Thank you,
moyo

Comment: It seem you have some ajax calls run instantly after page load

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too, but I cannot figure out why. Is there any way or tricks how to get the reason why the page is trigerring full reinitialization?

Comment: After hours of flustration, research, uncommenting the page controls I found the reason ... no AJAX, no custom controls ... the reason was the control definition `<asp:Image ID="imageCtrl" runat="server">` ... asp:Image must have ImageUrl defined, otherwise it causes page reinitialization after postback ... does anybody knows why?